# How to pivot or 'merge' rows with column names?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have the following table:

```
crit_id   | criterium  | val1  | val2
----------+------------+-------+--------
  1       |     T01    |   9   |   9
  2       |     T02    |   3   |   5
  3       |     T03    |   4   |   9
  4       |     T01    |   2   |   3
  5       |     T02    |   5   |   1
  6       |     T03    |   6   |   1
```

I need to convert the values in 'criterium' into columns as 'cross product' with val1 and val2. So the result has to lool like:

```
T01_val1 |T01_val2 |T02_val1 |T02_val2 | T03_val1 | T03_val2
---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------
   9     |   9     |    3    |    5    |    4     |    9
   2     |   3     |    5    |    1    |    6     |    1
```

Or to say differently: I need every value for all criteria to be in one row.

This is my current approach:

```
select 
   case when criterium = 'T01' then val1 else null end as T01_val1,
   case when criterium = 'T01' then val2 else null end as T01_val2,
   case when criterium = 'T02' then val1 else null end as T02_val1,
   case when criterium = 'T02' then val2 else null end as T02_val2,
   case when criterium = 'T03' then val1 else null end as T03_val1,
   case when criterium = 'T03' then val2 else null end as T04_val2,
from crit_table;
```

But the result looks not how I want it to look like:

```
T01_val1 |T01_val2 |T02_val1 |T02_val2 | T03_val1 | T03_val2
---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------
   9     |   9     |  null   |  null   |  null    |  null
   null  |  null   |    3    |    5    |  null    |  null
   null  |  null   |  null   |  null   |   4      |    9
```

What's the fastest way to achieve my goal?

*Bonus question:*

I have 77 criteria and seven different kinds of values for every criterium. So I have to write 539 `case` statements. Whats the best way to create them dynamically?

I'm working with PostgreSql 9.4

Comment: This is a pretty weird requirement. Is there some reason you MUST have the data out in this particular format? If you simply run "select criterium, val1, val2 from crit_table" it will get out exactly the data you need, without the problems of nasty variable geometry table views.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to export the data in this format.

Comment: does `val1  | val2` column name is like this upto `val7`?

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ, no, `val1` to `val7` are only placeholders to keep it simple. The real column names are in natural language like: `number_min`, `number_max`, `grade` and so on.

Comment: is there complete set of criteria per line or will there be gaps? and is the crit_id really without gaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Prepare for crosstab

In order to use [`crosstab()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tablefunc.html) function, the data must be reorganized. You need a dataset with three columns (`row number`, `criterium`, `value`). To have all values in one column you must *unpivot* two last columns, changing at the same time the names of criteria. As a row number you can use `rank()` function over partitions by new criteria.

```
select rank() over (partition by criterium order by crit_id), criterium, val
from (
    select crit_id, criterium || '_v1' criterium, val1 val
    from crit
    union
    select crit_id, criterium || '_v2' criterium, val2 val
    from crit
    ) sub
order by 1, 2

 rank | criterium | val 
------+-----------+-----
    1 | T01_v1    |   9
    1 | T01_v2    |   9
    1 | T02_v1    |   3
    1 | T02_v2    |   5
    1 | T03_v1    |   4
    1 | T03_v2    |   9
    2 | T01_v1    |   2
    2 | T01_v2    |   3
    2 | T02_v1    |   5
    2 | T02_v2    |   1
    2 | T03_v1    |   6
    2 | T03_v2    |   1
(12 rows)
```

This dataset can be used in `crosstab()`:

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select * from crosstab($ct$
    select rank() over (partition by criterium order by crit_id), criterium, val
    from (
        select crit_id, criterium || '_v1' criterium, val1 val
        from crit
        union
        select crit_id, criterium || '_v2' criterium, val2 val
        from crit
        ) sub
    order by 1, 2
    $ct$)
as ct (rank bigint, "T01_v1" int, "T01_v2" int, 
                    "T02_v1" int, "T02_v2" int, 
                    "T03_v1" int, "T03_v2" int);

 rank | T01_v1 | T01_v2 | T02_v1 | T02_v2 | T03_v1 | T03_v2
------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
    1 |      9 |      9 |      3 |      5 |      4 |      9
    2 |      2 |      3 |      5 |      1 |      6 |      1
(2 rows)
```

### Alternative solution

For 77 criteria * 7 parameters the above query may be troublesome. If you can accept a bit different way of presenting the data, the issue becomes much easier.

```
select * from crosstab($ct$
    select 
        rank() over (partition by criterium order by crit_id),
        criterium,
        concat_ws(' | ', val1, val2) vals
    from crit
    order by 1, 2
    $ct$)
as ct (rank bigint, "T01" text, "T02" text, "T03" text);

 rank |  T01  |  T02  |  T03
------+-------+-------+-------
    1 | 9 | 9 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 9
    2 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 6 | 1
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Quite an elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (crit_id int, criterium varchar(3), val1 int, val2 int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (crit_id, criterium, val1, val2)
VALUES
    (1, 'T01', 9, 9),
    (2, 'T02', 3, 5),
    (3, 'T03', 4, 9),
    (4, 'T01', 2, 3),
    (5, 'T02', 5, 1),
    (6, 'T03', 6, 1)
;

select [T01] As [T01_val1 ],[T01-1] As [T01_val2 ],[T02] As [T02_val1 ],[T02-1] As [T02_val2 ],[T03] As [T03_val1 ],[T03-1] As [T03_val3 ] from (
select T.criterium,T.val1,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.criterium ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN from (
select  criterium, val1 from @Table1
UNION ALL
select criterium+'-'+'1', val2 from @Table1)T)PP

PIVOT (MAX(val1) FOR criterium IN([T01],[T02],[T03],[T01-1],[T02-1],[T03-1]))P
```

Comment: Are you sure that this solution works in **PostgreSQL** ?

Comment: lets see what the questionnaire will say but it is purely SQL answer nothing to do with Postgresql

Comment: If so what's the use of `tag` here?.The OP tagged his question for `PostgreSQL`, And your solution ain't work in **PostgreSQL** though!

Comment: `DECLARE @Table1` is not "pure SQL" - it's T-SQL. Also `[T01]` or `@table1` is an invalid identifier in "pure SQL" `@`, `[` or `]` are not allowed in an SQL identifier and the concatenation operator in "pure SQL" is `||` not , `+`

Comment: Yes your points are valid. I agree with that but the same query will surely work in Postgresql . I have executed through online Converter. It will be fine. @ table variable is a sample table purpose . Sorry for my terms usage it is MSSQL not pure SQL

Comment: pivot does not work in postgresql either. and thats not just some syntactic sugar.

Comment: I'm trying to translate the query into PostgreSql but having trouble with `[T01]`, `[T02]` and so on in the outermost `select`. In the underlying data set I have the three columns: `criterium`, 'val1' and `RN`. So how do I translate them in Postgres?

Comment: @twenty7 please try in this converter

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael's comment that this requirement looks a bit weird, but if you really need it that way, you were on the right track with your solution. It just needs a little bit of additional code (and small corrections wherever val_1 and val_2 where mixed up):

```
select 
   sum(case when criterium = 'T01' then val_1 else null end) as T01_val1,
   sum(case when criterium = 'T01' then val_2 else null end) as T01_val2,
   sum(case when criterium = 'T02' then val_1 else null end) as T02_val1,
   sum(case when criterium = 'T02' then val_2 else null end) as T02_val2,
   sum(case when criterium = 'T03' then val_1 else null end) as T03_val1,
   sum(case when criterium = 'T03' then val_2 else null end) as T03_val2
from 
   crit_table
group by 
   trunc((crit_id-1)/3.0)
order by 
  trunc((crit_id-1)/3.0);
```

This works as follows. To aggregate the result you posted into the result you would like to have, the first helpful observation is that the desired result has less rows than your preliminary one. So there's some kind of grouping necessary, and the key question is: "What's the grouping criterion?" In this case, it's rather non-obvious: It's criterion ID (minus 1, to start counting with 0) divided by 3, and truncated. The three comes from the number of different criteria. After that puzzle is solved, it is easy to see that for among the input rows that are aggregated into the same result row, there is only one non-null value per column. That means that the choice of aggregate function is not so important, as it is only needed to return the only non-null value. I used the sum in my code snippet, but you could as well use min or max.

As for the bonus question: Use a code generator query that generates the query you need. The code looks like this (with only three types of values to keep it brief):

```
with value_table as  /* possible kinds of values, add the remaining ones here */
  (select 'val_1' value_type union 
   select 'val_2' value_type union  
   select 'val_3' value_type )
select contents from (
      select 0 order_id, 'select' contents
      union
          select row_number() over () order_id, 
                 'max(case when criterium = '''||criterium||''' then '||value_type||' else null end) '||criterium||'_'||value_type||',' contents
            from crit_table
      cross join value_table
      union select 9999999 order_id, 
                   '    from crit_table  group by trunc((crit_id-1)/3.0) order by  trunc((crit_id-1)/3.0);' contents
      ) v
order by order_id;
```

This basically only uses a string template of your query and then inserts the appropriate combinations of values for the criteria and the val-columns. You could even get rid of the with-clause by reading column names from information_schema.columns, but I think the basic idea is clearer in the version above. Note that the code generated contains one comma too much directly after the last column (before the from clause). It's easier to delete that by hand afterwards than correcting it in the generator.

Comment: Your solution provides exactly the same result as my approach

Comment: I very much hope so! The OP has defined the result, so we should both get the same. The solution approaches also share some ideas, at least as far as I'm able to see without investing too much time into decoding T-SQL, which is a bit hard to read for me.